# Which glue isn't detrimental to laptop electronics

Tags: repair, laptop, glue

Over time, I lost all four rubber feet that were under my laptop (Asus UX530U) and I want to replace them. The original ones used to stick to the laptop by having a little rubber pin plugged into the aluminum case through a hole, and also being glued to it. The original rubbers aren't available anymore, so I bought other ones with the right size. Since they don't have plugs to go into the case like the original ones, I need to glue the new rubber feet to the case.

I fear that I could use a glue that would prove detrimental to the electronic parts inside, given that the glue will be situated around holes in the case and of course that the laptop will heat the glue when used, which I guess will cause the glue to release some kinds of chemicals through the holes in the case.

Is there a specific kind/category of glues that I should avoid because it could harm the electronics inside?

Additionally, I should still be able to remove the rubber feet if need be because there are screws beneath them.

Comment: use "3M" double sided tape?

Comment: You are not applying the glue to the electronics. If you encounter a glue that emits fumes that damage electronics, then you should be more worried how the fumes affect your health.

Comment: @Justme Indeed I'm not applying it directly to the electronics, but close to it. I'm not knowledgeable enough about neither glues nor electronics to assess if the proximity could cause issues, particularly because of the heat of the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double-sided polyimide ("Kapton" is one brand) tape, rather than liquid glue which can be hard to control and messy to remove. Polyimide tape is designed for use around sensitive electronics. It's even available in small disc shapes, but it will be easier to obtain as a 1/2" wide roll which you can cut into the shape and size of your rubber feet. Apply it to the laptop, peel off the backing, and stick on the feet.

Comment: @OP Just make sure that whatever tape you choose isn't described as "permanent". Very high bond (VHB) might also be troublesome if you did need to remove the feet.

Comment: Thanks, it the end the rubber feet I ordered actually had their own glue/tape, so I didn't need any other.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a valid concern, but there really aren’t any glues that - when used on the exterior of the laptop’s case - would affect the electronics inside.

One potentially iffy glue would be the vinegar-smelling silicone polymer. The acetic acid produced while it cures can corrode electronics. But: 1) it’s not a great glue for this application, and 2) there is a version that doesn’t produce acetic acid while curing, if you insisted on using it.

Comment: Cyanoacrylates (super-glue & friends) give off vapors which can form insulating layers in nearby switches & connectors even when not used directly on them.

Comment: @brhans I learn something new every day! Thank you.